# Bridging React props to JS only setters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sometimes, one may want to use a prop to set an element property that can only be set through JS (hence, uncontrollable through React).

An example (and my use case) is using a `paused` property to define if a video should be playing or not (my goal is to dissociate the control and the visualization of a video).

Here is what my current (simplified) implementation:

```js
class Video extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.videoElRef = this.videoElRef.bind(this);
  }
  // Called when the video element is mounted.
  videoElRef(ref) {
    this.videoEl = ref;
    if (this.videoEl) {
      this.updateVideoProp();
    }
  }
  // Update JS only property from the Component props.
  updateVideoProp() {
    const { paused } = this.props;
    const videoEl = this.videoEl;
    // Pause or play the video depending on the `paused` property.
    if (paused && !videoEl.paused) {
      videoEl.pause();
    } else if (!paused && videoEl.paused) {
      videoEl.play();
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (this.videoEl) {
      this.updateVideoProp();
    }
    return (
      <video ref={this.videoElRef}>
        { this.props.children }
      </video>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
const Component = React.Component;

class Video extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.videoElRef = this.videoElRef.bind(this);
  }
  // Called when the video element is mounted.
  videoElRef(ref) {
    this.videoEl = ref;
    if (this.videoEl) {
      this.updateVideoProp();
    }
  }
  // Update JS only property from the Component props.
  updateVideoProp() {
    const { paused } = this.props;
    const videoEl = this.videoEl;
    // Pause or play the video depending on the `paused` property.
    if (paused && !videoEl.paused) {
      videoEl.pause();
    } else if (!paused && videoEl.paused) {
      videoEl.play();
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (this.videoEl) {
      this.updateVideoProp();
    }
    return (
      <video ref={this.videoElRef}>
        { this.props.children }
      </video>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { paused: true };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  onClick(){
    this.setState(state => ({ ...state, paused: !this.state.paused }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <Video paused={this.state.paused}>
          <source
            src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov"
            type="video/mp4"
          />
        </Video>
        <p><button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.paused?'play':'pause'}</button></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
video {
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It works fine. However, I find it quite hacky. E.g. modifying the `paused` property does not actually require the component to be re-rendered and the `updateVideoProp` method is called as a side-effect of the `render` trigger.

I cannot find the right pattern to achieve this. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think contents of `updateVideoProp` method actually belongs in `componentDidUpdate` method, or if you want to change property before render is called then use `componentWillRecieveProps` method.

Comment: Right, `componentDidUpdate` absolutely looks like a better place for this piece of code. I am still a bit annoyed by the useless `render` call though.

Comment: I suppose the play button exists in parent component. So, video component only has props to rely on and rendering will happen when props are changed.

Comment: Yes. It is possible there is no way to go around this extra render. It is not too bad though, now that thanks to you I know where to put the update code.